# Can the details tag display its vertical content beside the summary content?

Tags: html, css

I apologize in advance if this is a dumb question.  I really haven't a lot of experience, and I'm just experimenting to see what does what. This is also more of a theoretical question than anything, since I don't have a current use, but I'm curious all the same.

*Using only CSS*, and preferably no `pseudo-classes`, is it possible to force a details tag, upon opening, to display it's content `_beside_` the summary tag content?

That is as if you were using `flex-direction` on two divs to get them to display side-by-side.  I really don't see why it wouldn't be possible, but the closest I can get is setting `details` to `display:contents` inside a flex parent div, which obviously isn't ideal.

As I said, I'm just playing around with what can and cannot be done using `<details>`, so this isn't much of anything.  I'm also using inline-css because, well, *like I said*, I'm just playing around. But this is essentially what I'm looking to do (without the use of the parent div and `display:contents` ):

```html
<div class="boxes" style="display: flex; margin: 10px auto; padding: 0 20px;">
    <details style="display: contents;filter: grayscale(100%); width: 33%;">
        <summary style="background-color:#d80000;background-position: center center; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: cover; height: 200px; outline: 1px solid #ffffff; outline-offset: -15px; color: #ffffff; text-align: center; padding-top: 25px; font-size: 0;">
            <span style="display: block; font-size: 10px; letter-spacing: 4px; margin-bottom: 5px; text-transform: uppercase;">Title</span>
        </summary>
        <article style="border: 1px solid #000000; padding: 10px; font-size: 12px;">
            Here's stuff
        </article>
    </details>
</div>
```

Comment: change the parent flex container to be flex-direction row and the children will be side by side

Comment: That's what I thought, too, but I can't get it to work.  Granted, my knowledge of how flex works is abysmal.